# Riddle De Do, Riddle De Dum

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

"Hello" you say

and just and friendly I'd speak back.

Yet it's a lie, I only quote

that welcoming into my throat.

Surely, you think, they're just for show,

those fangs you see both high and low

and though my heart's as black as night

you needn't worry - I won't bite.

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll

swallowing anything that comes to me whole.

My skin is thicker than any bruit,

yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

What am I?

Comment: Do you really mean "bruit"? Sounds aren't thick.

Comment: @HughMeyers Oh that round and reddish sound ;)

Comment: @HughMeyers Clearly you have never heard my bass riffs

Comment: @question_asker "You've got to hear electric music, solid walls of sound."

Comment: Did you mean "just as friendly", by the way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Hello" you say
and just and friendly I'd speak back.
Yet it's a lie, I only quote
that welcoming into my throat.

> An Echo

Surely, you think, they're just for show,
those fangs you see both high and low
and though my heart's as black as night
you needn't worry - I won't bite.

> Stalagmites/tites

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll
swallowing anything that comes to me whole.
My skin is thicker than any bruit,
yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

Taking the other hints into account:

> You are a cave/ a cave mouth

Comment: You should rearrange your explanations so that your answer comes first.

Comment: I know others got the correct answer as well, but you got the answer first so you get the correct answer mark. Good job :)

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like :

> A **Telephone**

"Hello" you say 
and just and friendly I'd speak back. 
Yet it's a lie, I only quote 
that welcoming into my throat.

> We say "Hello" and the other end replies "hello" as well. It's a lie because the phone doesn't speak it only quotes the person who talks to its throat(Receiver.)

Surely, you think, they're just for show, 
those fangs you see both high and low 
and though my heart's as black as night 
you needn't worry - I won't bite.

> The fangs are the buttons on the receiver end as well as the keypad. The heart is black might be a reference to its battery or the chip sets, and yes the phone doesn't bite.

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll 
swallowing anything that comes to me whole. 
My skin is thicker than any bruit, 
yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

> Telephones can seem ugly trolls or they can be used for trolling. Bruit means spreading a rumor widely. Thicker skin can be a reference to "phones can spread rumors very rapidly."
>  Alone, its always mute. it only comes to life when someone calls.

What am I?

> a Telephone.

Answer (score 3):

You are...

> a cave.

"Hello" you say
and just and friendly I'd speak back.

> You talk into the mouth and it echoes back.

Surely, you think, they're just for show,
those fangs you see both high and low
and though my heart's as black as night
you needn't worry - I won't bite.

> Stalactites and stalagmites are the fangs.

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll
swallowing anything that comes to me whole.

> As you walk in you are swallowed whole.

My skin is thicker than any bruit,

> The whole earth is the thick skin.

yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

> No sound unless someone or something makes a sound inside.

Comment: It is customary to hide your answers with spoiler tags `>!`, quoting the bits of the riddle outside of the spoilers so it is easy to follow.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE. The answer itself was fine, it just needed a bit of editing.

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is

> A fun-house ride. The only problem is, it seems too literal.

"Hello" you say 
and just and friendly I'd speak back. 
Yet it's a lie, I only quote 
that welcoming into my throat.

> Lots of people when they go into these rides yell "hello!" to hear the echo, I suppose. I've never really understood this. The ride usually has some sort of greeting that plays over and over in a loop, so it's a quote rather than a real welcome.

Surely, you think, they're just for show, 
those fangs you see both high and low 
and though my heart's as black as night 
you needn't worry - I won't bite.

> The entrance is often a mouth. The ride is usually dark inside and, though it may look scary, is actually safe.

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll 
swallowing anything that comes to me whole. 
My skin is thicker than any bruit, 
yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

> The cars or boats of the ride go into the mouth hole. The sides are plywood and canvas - thicker than any "brute"'s hide. It is operated by the guy at the switches and it goes dead whenever the power is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely

> A cave:
>  A dead, thick-skinned object with echoes, a black heart of darkness, non biting fangs of stalactites and stalagmites

Comment: you might want to explains each line of the riddle how your answer fit in

Comment: I did, just tersely

Answer (score 0):

I think you're:

> Siri

"Hello" you say
and just and friendly I'd speak back.

> Speak to Siri and she (or he) will reply

Yet it's a lie, I only quote
that welcoming into my throat.

> All the answers are pre-programmed

Surely, you think, they're just for show,
those fangs you see both high and low

> Those sound wave when you speak that looks like fangs

and though my heart's as black as night 
you needn't worry - I won't bite.

> The phone itself

Rather I'm much like a fairy tale troll
swallowing anything that comes to me whole.

> You can tell / ask Siri about anything

My skin is thicker than any bruit, 
yet I haven't life and alone I'm mute.

> Phone case, and Siri is only a program and do not speak if not activated

What am I?

> Siri